# Drag and Drop of a div in html5 displays transparent at dragstart

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, appearance

Is there any way to control appearance of drag and drop. I gone through the following link to achieve by cloning a div

https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/custom-drag-image.html

Code is as follows:

```
elemDragStart(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    var crtElem = event.currentTarget.cloneNode(true);
    crtElem.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    crtElem.style.position = "absolute";
    crtElem.style.left = (event.currentTarget.offsetLeft) + "px";
    crtElem.style.top = (event.currentTarget.offsetTop) + "px";

    document.body.appendChild(this.crtElem);
    event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(this.crtElem, 0, 0);
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', event.currentTarget.innerHTML);
    event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(event.currentTarget, 0, 0);
}
```

But it displays as follows:

[image]

I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: why are you setting the drag image twice?

Comment: you've set a drag image which is `crtElem` but then you replaced it with the original element `event.currentTarget`

Comment: Still its not working.I did changed to crtElem from event.currentTarget, It show the same pattern

Comment: Do you have a working example of your code? jsfiddle maybe?

Comment: I gave a sample workaround with similar code. https://jsfiddle.net/8bL4mez3/